Unable to create Kubernetes namespace using io.kubernetes API in Java
I'm attempting to create a Kubernetes namespace in my cluster using the io.kubernetes API with Java 17 in IntelliJ IDEA. Despite not encountering any errors or exceptions, the namespace isn't being created successfully. Below is the relevant code snippet:
V1Namespace v1Namespace = new V1Namespace();
V1ObjectMeta metadata = new V1ObjectMeta();
metadata.setName(namespace);
v1Namespace.setMetadata(metadata);
v1Namespace.setApiVersion("v1");
v1Namespace.setKind("Namespace");
api.createNamespace(v1Namespace);

However, when I attempt to fetch namespaces using the API, it works correctly:
V1Namespace v1Namespace = api.readNamespace("dev-shez").execute();

Here's the configuration part of my code:
String kubeConfigPath = "\\path\\kubeconfig";
FileReader kubeConfigFileReader = new FileReader(kubeConfigPath);
ApiClient client = ClientBuilder.kubeconfig(KubeConfig.loadKubeConfig(kubeConfigFileReader)).build();
Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client);
CoreV1Api api = new CoreV1Api();
api.setApiClient(client);

Do I need to implement any additional conditions or configurations for the creation API to work properly?

Changing the io.kubernetes version from 20.x.x to 15.0.1 resolved the issue.
